# How to check if a string contains a substring in a Windows .bat file

Tags: android, batch-file

I'm trying to create a .bat script to install .apk files via the adb (android debugging bridge) on android devices. So far this is my sourcecode:

```
@echo off
@echo Plug in ONE VR headset and enable USB debugging on the device
@echo Press any button to continue
PAUSE

:step0
CD /d C:\Users\alexq\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
adb kill-server
adb start-server
:step1
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('adb devices') DO SET result=%%g
echo %result% | FINDSTR /I "device">nul && IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO step2 ELSE GOTO step3

:step2
echo Could not find attached device or USB debugging is not enabled
echo Check USB connection of VR headset
echo Enable USB debugging on the VR headset
echo Press any button to try again
PAUSE
GOTO step1

:step3
echo found device
rem WIP more stuff will be added
PAUSE
```

My problem seems to be in this line `echo %result% | FINDSTR /I "device">nul && IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO step2 ELSE GOTO step3`. The output of `echo %result%` is a device number and the word *device* when the device is ready, here an example: `61047ce9        device`(Yes there are these empty spaces between the number and the word device).

I want that the script checks whether the word device is in this result and then goes to step3 when it finds it.
My problem is that right now the script always jumps to step2, so the device is not ready even thought it is (i checked it manually).
Does somebody knows where my error is?

thx in advance

Comment: I would suggest replacing that line with `Echo(%result%|FindStr /I "device">NUL&&GoTo step3`. Although `('ADB Devices 2^>NUL^|Find /I "Device"')` may be a little more efficient with some other small modifications.

Comment: Example: `Set "result="`, then `For /F %%g In ('ADB Devices 2^>NUL^|Find "device"') Do Set "result=%%g"`, and `If Defined result GoTo step3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer based upon the advice from my comments:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "%LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools" 2>NUL||Exit /B 1
Echo Plug in ONE VR headset and enable USB debugging on the device
Pause

ADB kill-server
ADB start-server

:Step1
Set "result="
For /F %%A In ('ADB Devices 2^>NUL^|Find "device"') Do Set "result=%%A"
If Defined result GoTo Step3

:Step2
Echo Could not find attached device or USB debugging is not enabled
Echo Check USB connection of VR headset
Echo Enable USB debugging on the VR headset
Pause
GoTo Step1

:Step3
Echo found device %result%
Rem WIP more stuff will be added
Pause
```

Comment: Thx this works fine :). Could you explain what the 2>NUL does after the cd command?

Comment: Yes, it simply redirects any error resulting from the `CD` command to the `NUL` device, _(effectively hides it)_. Basically what the line does is it tries to make the `platform-tools` directory current, if that fails, _probably because it doesn't exist in that location_, it hides the error message, and because you will not have `adb.exe`, available, it closes your script.